# how can i set text from string arraylist?

Tags: android, string, arraylist, textview, settext

I did some mistake but I can't understand what is the right way to do it. Below is my code which I tried.
I made MainActivity , database helper , note model class , and add note activity. when i add data into database it works fine and i also get data in to recyclerview but i want first 3 note data on Mainactivity to display text then i tried hard to do it but i cant set text to textviw in mainActivity

String from array list noteTitle 
---MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView topNoteTitle, topNoteDetail, leftNoteTitle, leftNoteDetail, rightNoteTitle, rightNoteDetail;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        topNoteTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_top_note_title);
        topNoteDetail = findViewById(R.id.tv_top_note_detail);
        leftNoteTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_left_note_tag);
        leftNoteDetail = findViewById(R.id.tv_left_note_subject);
        rightNoteTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_right_note_tag);
        rightNoteDetail = findViewById(R.id.tv_right_note_subject);


        String title = ApplicationClass.noteTitle.get(2);
        String titleOne = ApplicationClass.noteTitle.get(0) ;
        String titleTwo = ApplicationClass.noteTitle.get(1); 
        String detail = ApplicationClass.noteDetail.get(2); 
        String detailOne = ApplicationClass.noteDetail.get(0);
        String detailTwo = ApplicationClass.noteDetail.get(1);

        rightNoteTitle.setText(title);
        topNoteTitle.setText(titleOne);
        leftNoteTitle.setText(titleTwo);
        rightNoteDetail.setText(detail);
        topNoteDetail.setText(detailOne); 
        leftNoteDetail.setText(detailTwo);
```

Dbhelper class

datastore part is working properly so I am sharing the only method

```
    public ArrayList<String> getThreeTitle(){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String noteTitle = "SELECT note_tag  FROM " + TODO_NOTES;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(noteTitle,null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getThreeDetail(){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String noteTitle = "SELECT note_detail  FROM " + TODO_NOTES;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(noteTitle,null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Application class

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(ApplicationClass.this);

    public static ArrayList<String> noteTitle;
    public static ArrayList<String> noteDetail;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        noteTitle = dbHelper.getThreeTitle();
        noteDetail = dbHelper.getThreeDetail();
}}
```

please help me i am stuck hear ..

xml layout is here

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardFrag">

     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="334dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:elevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_todo_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/mon_semibold"
                        android:onClick="NotesActivity"
                        android:text="My Notes"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/line" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_note" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="7"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_top_note_title"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mon_semibold"
                                android:text="Note Tag" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_top_note_detail"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mon_regular"
                                android:text="Text Note Subject Line will be here and try one is this" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/line" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="144dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_left_note_tag"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mon_semibold"
                                android:text="Another Tag " />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_left_note_subject"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mon_regular"
                                android:text="Second note subject Will be here and bla bla bla blaa blaband just checking" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/line" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_right_note_tag"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mon_semibold"
                                android:text="Another Tag " />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_right_note_subject"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/mon_regular"
                                android:text="Second note subject Will be here and bla bla bla blaa blaband just checking" />


                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/line" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_see_all"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        android:onClick="NotesActivity"
                        android:text="See All" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyvrj.png)

[error are in this screenshote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VgK7.png)

[in string i geting right data but cant set them to textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnHdq.png)

Comment: What isn't working? How are you writing to the ArrayLists? How are you initializing the TextViews?

Comment: Do you have any exception/crash/problem? If yes, provide exception stack trace (from console/logcat). Add also your `onCreate()` method content.

Comment: Does `activity_main.xml` contain the 6 `TextView` and have you double-checked their IDs?

Comment: yes 6 textview are there and 6 string i have. i want assign that value to 6 textview

Comment: question is can i assign string to textview directly and also added screenshot of debug mode

Comment: This should work. Perhaps post your layout file.

Comment: now  I added xml layout also

Comment: ok i got my problem i made wrong structer of bottom navigation view thank you so much both of you